# Como eu consigo recuperar o File explorer no menu lateral do VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Eu estou com um problema, no pc do escritório aquele ícone do file explorer que fica no menu lateral do vs code sumiu, mesmo abrindo o projeto ou a pasta do projeto ele não paparece.
Para aparecer eu uso o CTRL+SHIFT+E e vejo os arquivos que preciso, mas ao escolher o arquivo ele some novamente.

Eu queria deixar fixo.

Alguém sabe onde configuro isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clique com o botão direito na lateral e selecione as opções que estão desmarcadas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado @Felipe Moreira

Comment: Sem problemas, cara!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta utilizar Ctrl + B ou Menu View

[[image: 1]

Comment: Obrigado jovem @rxpha, todas as opções dão certo. Mas para fixar mesmo só deu certo clicando com o botão direito na lateral e selecionando a opção explorer.

Comment: e quando o explore não está na opção do botão direito?